# Can I define a function which returns a reference to an array with a fixed size?

Tags: c++

This function accepts an int, and fill an array of 10 ints with that value, and returns a pointer to that array. How can I do the same thing but return an reference to an array?

```
int (*g(int n))[10]
{
    int (*ptr)[10] = (int (*)[10])malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        (*ptr)[i] = n;
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Something like

```
int (&h(int n))[10]
{
    // How to do this
    int (&ref)[10] = ???;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ref[i] = n;
    }
    return ref;
}
```

Comment: You'll need an array that you want the reference to refer to...

Comment: Use std::array instead, clearer and more 'idiomatic' C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way, but dereference it before returning:

```
int (&h(int n))[10]
{
    return *g(n);
}
```

or (less briefly)

```
int (&h(int n))[10]
{
    int (*ptr)[10] = (int (*)[10])malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        (*ptr)[i] = n;
    }
    return *ptr;
}
```

or more explicity

```
int (&h(int n))[10]
{
    int (*ptr)[10] = (int (*)[10])malloc(sizeof(int) * 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        (*ptr)[i] = n;
    }
    int& ref = *ptr;
    return ref;
}
```

Comment: int& ref = *ptr; it seems this one is not right. g++ reports error: invalid conversion from ‘int * ’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
     int &ref = *ptr;